# When did the term "Jay" come to mean an "unintelligent person"?

Tags: etymology

While I was reading [an article about the etymology of *jaywalking*](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/07/origin-of-the-term-jaywalking/), I stumbled upon this phrase:

> “Jay” used to be a generic term for someone who was an idiot, dull, rube, unsophisticated, poor, or simpleton.

When did people used to use the term *Jay* as *unintelligent person*(or idiot)?

Answer (score 1):

In the 1620s according to [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/?term=jay).

Comment: Your reference say: "Applied to humans in sense of "impertinent chatterer, flashy dresser" from 1620s." I would say this is not entirely the same as what is asked in the question. I would say it needs other answers for when this was taken further to mean "unintelligent person".

Comment: Surely an impertinent chatterer would be considered unintelligent in the 17th century, a person of education would have known when to speak and when not to, as well as what to speak about and what not to.